# How to understand / calculate FLOPs of the neural network model?

Tags: neural-networks, conv-neural-network

In [the paper on ResNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.03385.pdf), authors say, that their 152-layer network has lesser complexity than VGG network with 16 or 19 layers:

> We construct 101- layer and 152-layer ResNets by using more 3-layer
>   blocks (Table 1). Remarkably, although the depth is significantly
>   increased, the 152-layer ResNet (11.3 billion FLOPs) still has lower
>   complexity than VGG-16/19 nets (15.3/19.6 billion FLOPs)

page 7 top.

How can it be?

Answer (score 4):

```
input_shape = (3,300,300) # Format:(channels, rows,cols)
conv_filter = (64,3,3,3)  # Format: (num_filters, channels, rows, cols)
stride = 1
padding = 1
activation = 'relu'

n = conv_filter[1] * conv_filter[2] * conv_filter[3]  # vector_length
flops_per_instance = n + 1    # general defination for number of flops (n: multiplications and n-1: additions)

num_instances_per_filter = (( input_shape[1] - conv_filter[2] + 2*padding) / stride ) + 1  # for rows
num_instances_per_filter *= (( input_shape[2] - conv_filter[3] + 2*padding) / stride ) + 1 # multiplying with cols

flops_per_filter = num_instances_per_filter * flops_per_instance
total_flops_per_layer = flops_per_filter * conv_filter[0]    # multiply with number of filters

if activation == 'relu':
    # Here one can add number of flops required
    # Relu takes 1 comparison and 1 multiplication
    # Assuming for Relu: number of flops equal to length of input vector
    total_flops_per_layer += conv_filter[0]*num_instances_per_filter


print(total_flops_per_layer)
```

This might help you.

Comment: An anonymous attempted editor argues that the last line should be: `total_flops_per_layer += conv_filter[0]*num_instances_per_filter`, because, "In general, flops of relu equals num_filter * output_feature_map_size."

Comment: @gung Yes, the RELU should be operated on the output matrix.

Comment: for cols it should be `input_shape[2]` and `conv_filter[3]`, right?